# Setup sonar-runner for multiple java projects

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am trying to run sonar-runner to analyze multiple Java projects in one go. According to the [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner) it is just a matter of creating a `sonar-project.properties` file for each project. But it is not clear to me where exactly I have to put these sonar-project.properties files.

I tried to add multiple .properties files in the `$SONAR_RUNNER_HOME/conf` folder but the runner does not seem to pick them up. It only sees the sonar-project.properties file.

Any suggestions on how to run sonar-runner for multiple projects?

Answer (score 22):

Actually it is quite simple to let the sonar runner analyze multiple projects as long as they are in the same file system. Just put a properties file in a directory that is not to far away from the projects. Then declare each of your projects in this properties file.

Lets assume you have 4 projects in dev/general/BasicStuff, dev/service/CoolStuff, dev/utility/UtilStuff and dev/display/FrameWorkStuff.

As described in [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner)Way #2 you create a file in dev which contains the line

```
sonar.modules=BasicStuff,CoolStuff,UtilStuff,FrameWorkStuff
```

And for each of the "modules" a line like

```
BasicStuff.sonar.projectBaseDir=general/BasicStuff
CoolStuff.sonar.projectBaseDir=service/CoolStuff
```

Inside the project directories you in turn create a file which contains the other needed information, e.g.

```
sonar.projectName=BasicStuff
sonar.sources=src
```

If you start sonar runner with the top level properties as target you get a comprehensive result which shows metrics across the projects as well as allowing you to drill into each of them.

Hope this was what you were looking for.

Comment: Incredibly useful.  I tweaked this to work with a Jenkins/Sonar build and it saved a ton of time.  Only had to create one build job instead of 11.

Answer (score 12):

The Sonar runner supports projects with multiple modules. It doesn't support the analysis of multiple projects in one invocation.

The Java runner needs to be run against each project, picking up the properties file in each project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2.0, Sonar runner works with multiple modules, as described [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner)

Comment: the question is about **multiple projects** and not **multiple modules** in the same project. Are you saying that the link that you mentioned works for multiple java projects too. Mark O'Connor in his answer has mentioned that it does not support the analysis of multiple projects in one invocation.

Comment: First of all link is dead, but secondly, looks like project vs. module definition is from perspective of sonar runner... In that case you can define a project and pass different source directories, which would include sources of different projects, so long as they're accessible from your file system. That would give you a "project" snapshot of multiple java projects in one sonar project analyses.