# SonarQube: How to analyze projects that share multiple modules?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I have four projects, which have several modules in common.

When I try to run a SonarQube complete analysis, only the first project gets successfully analyzed. Starting with the second project, I get an error message along the lines of "XXX module is already present in the server".

Each of my four projects contains an aggregator POM. This is what I use to build them and to run the Maven sonar:sonar goal.

What would be the best approach to solve this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems you're breaking component/module/library conventions or mis used it. From `Configuration Management` principles you're not supposed to "include" (build in the case of Binary Configuration Management) your component multiple times.

Having a library which have many other ones which depends on and last ones are independant is just a dependancy that you have to manage appart like any other framework.

You're just supposed to install/deploy this component on his own and then just refer to it. Same principles apply on `SonarQube Configuration Manager`. You can't have shared components analyzed through different "products".

They must have their own life cycle. How do you manage evolution of shared librairies when having the four projects living in parallel of each others ?

Comment: That is actually not the issue here. I can also build a multi-module project and apply Sonar on it. The problem happens when I have multiple multi-module projects that share modules. Then, the shared modules cannot be all uploaded to SonarQube, since Sonar only allows **one** instance of a component to exist at any given time.

Comment: You're just breaking `Configuration Management` principles. See my edited post for more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Select a master project in which to analyze the shared modules; analyze that project first.

In the other (subsequent) projects, exclude the shared modules from SonarQube analysis by adding the following to the pom.xml of the shared modules:

```xml
<properties>
    <sonar.skip>true</sonar.skip>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

If by shared modules, you mean that the module is present in both Project A and Project B then yes, It will create a problem because SONAR only allows one instance of a Module to be present.

What you can do is run SONAR on your Project 1 then clear the workspace and again run it for Project 2.. and So on...

That way you would have only one instance of a module in SONAR at a time.

you can probably write a script for executing the SONAR jobs one by one and create a new job for that in Jenkins.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean with "shared modules". However, I've got a question: What you mean by "clear the workspace"?

Comment: check This out... It might be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487602/setup-sonar-runner-for-multiple-java-projects