# Running SonarQube on Multiple Project (Not Multiple Module)

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I want run Sonar on **Multiple Project (Not Multiple Module)** in single run(All are Java projects).

For Ex:
I have the Folder structure as below

RootFolder

```
   |--- Project1
   |--- Project2
   |--- Project3
```

I want to run Sonar on Project1,Project2 and Project3  in single run.

For Ex:  If i run Sonar on 'Rootfolder' report should be generated for all project(Project1,Project2 etc..) and in sonar dash board should be single entry with all project inside that.

I used sonar-runner but it runs on individual Project Level ,But i need at root level so that in single run i get the result

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

You've actually listed two goals in your question:

1. analyze multiple projects in a single run.
2. view multiple projects in a single, aggregate dashboard.

The first is not possible. The second is, but to accomplish it you'll need to analyze each project individually, then aggregate them using the commercial [Views Plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by using sonar.modules
The solution is described in below

[Setup sonar-runner for multiple java projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487602/setup-sonar-runner-for-multiple-java-projects)