# SonarQube batch analysis of multiple projects

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have several solutions written by students for a problem/project they had to solve. I'm trying to find a way to improve future projects.
These projects are written are in Java and are run against the same tests. Currently I have set up a CI pipeline that builds, tests and performs a code analysis with SonarQube (for the moment with a local instance, but I will be moving everything online of course).
This allows every student to have a personal feedback, but I would also like to perform a batch analysis myself on all of these projects and aggregate the results (the most frequent issues found, for example).

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16529210/11024409), but I've read the that this way of doing is now deprecated or not viable anymore.
Do you have any suggestions as to which solutions may fit my case? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.